# Sails.js image not caching even after adding response header

Tags: node.js, sails.js, cache-control

I am trying to add headers to images that I stream to the client in Sails.js. For this I have created a policy that runs before I output the image file.

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=200",
        "Expires": "SOME EXPIRY DATE"
    });
    next();
};
```

My response header has changed and looks like the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Sails <sailsjs.org>
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 
Cache-Control: private, max-age=200
Expires: Sun Oct 12 2014 23:18:39 GMT
Date: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 17:33:39 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

However, when I load the page again the browser seems to request for the image again. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Are you running Sails.js in development or production mode? In development mode, Sails.js sets max_age to 0 for all assets, while in production mode, max-age=31536000. Also, in Sails.js headers can be set with res.set().

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of you config/http.js

```
module.exports.cache = {
   // The number of seconds to cache files being served from disk
    maxAge: 86400000 // millsec = 24 hours
};
```